# Open/Close activity with proximity sensor

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sensors

I would like to create an application for my just bought transparent phone cover.
When the cover closes, I need an activity to open, and when the cover is open, to return to the "desktop".
So I created a service with following code inside :

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(event.values[0] == 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cover closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent panel = new Intent(this, Panel.class);
    panel.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
    startActivity(panel);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cover opened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //CODE HERE ?
    }
}
```

How could I close/hide my intent in order to return to android ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand you. Do you just want your application to finish, or are you just wanting to background the app?

Comment: I don't know what would be better. My aim is to open/close the activity when the cover closes/opens.

Comment: What do you want the user to experience; a backgrounded app, no app in the background or is there another activity you want them to see?

Comment: When the cover is open, I want the user to be able to use android normally, but when the cover close, I'd like to display an activity. And this activity should close when the cover is opened.